# Write time date series using in NetCDF python

Tags: python, pandas, time, netcdf4

I have created a time series using pandas like this:

`date_series_min = pd.date_range(yy+'-'+mm, periods=44640, freq='T')`

Where yy are years (ex: 2001) and mm are months (ex: 01) from a file name.
then I used the method indicated above to create a times series of dates each minute.
I see that the variable type for this series is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

How I can write this time series in a netCDF file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please revise your question. This code is not reproducible. It also does not produce a meaingful time series, just a datetimeindex. Why would you want to store that as a netCDF file?

Comment: I have a dataset which is collected each minute and I only have the date which was collected (ex: 2001-01, which is year and month). I want to create a NetCDF file for these data where also time is also included as a variable. Hopefully this make more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite. You need to make it clear what you are trying to do. Just posting code fragments just leaves people guessing. Revise the question showing a fully reproducible version of what you have done and what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

I made a script like this, where I use netCDF4 library to save the netCDf file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------
import pandas as pd
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
import datetime
# ----------------------
yy = '2001';mm='01';
date_series_min = pd.date_range(yy+'-'+mm, periods=44640, freq='T') # This is DatetimeIndex, perhaps ordinary datetime objects are preferred...
datesout = date_series_min.to_pydatetime() 
# ----------------------
unout = 'days since 2001-01-01 00:00:00'
fileout = 'test.nc'
# ----------------------
with Dataset(fileout,'w','NETCDF3') as ncout:
    ncout.createDimension('time',None);
    timevar = ncout.createVariable('time','float32',('time'));timevar.setncattr('units',unout);
    timevar[:]= date2num(datesout,unout);
```

The output from console (`ncdump -h $fileout` ) is like this:

```
netcdf test {
 dimensions:    time = UNLIMITED ; // (44640 currently) 
 variables:     
     float time(time) ;         
           time:units = "days since 2001-01-01 00:00:00" ; 
}
```